# Custom MarshalJSON() never gets called in Go

Tags: json, go, marshalling

I've written custom versions of `MarshalJSON` and `UnmarshalJSON`. My `UnmarshalJSON` gets called the way I want it to, but I can't get it to work with `MarshalJSON`. Here's code that summarizes my problem:

```
package main

import (
    "bytes"
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "os"
)

type myStruct struct {
    Data string `json:"data"`
}

func (s *myStruct) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    return []byte(`{"data":"charlie"}`), nil
}

func (s *myStruct) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) error {
    // Insert the string directly into the Data member
    return json.Unmarshal(b, &s.Data)
}

func main() {
    // Create a struct with initial content "alpha"
    ms := myStruct{"alpha"}

    // Replace content with "bravo" using custom UnmarshalJSON() (SUCCESSFUL)
    if err := json.NewDecoder(bytes.NewBufferString(`"bravo"`)).Decode(&ms); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Use custom MarshalJSON() to get "charlie" back (UNSUCCESSFUL)
    if err := json.NewEncoder(os.Stdout).Encode(ms); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    // Trying another method (UNSUCCESSFUL)
    if ret, err := json.Marshal(ms); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    } else {
        fmt.Println(string(ret))
    }

    // Verify that the Marshaler interface is correctly implemented
    var marsh json.Marshaler
    marsh = &ms
    ret, _ := marsh.MarshalJSON()
    fmt.Println(string(ret)) // Prints "charlie"
}
```

In short, the program encodes the `struct` "automatically" in two ways, and then finally calls `MarshalJSON` manually. The response I want is `"charlie"`. Running the code generates the following output:

```
{"data":"bravo"}
{"data":"bravo"}
{"data":"charlie"}
```

Try it at Go Playground: http://play.golang.org/p/SJ05S8rAYN

Comment: Just replaced `ms` to `&ms` in unsuccessful examples and it works for me: http://play.golang.org/p/VfZYuNkjmq. But I can't explain why, only suggestion, so we should wait for somebody who knows exactly.

Comment: Kavu has the solution. Your method applies to *myStruct, not myStruct.

Comment: @Kavu Thanks! Can't believe I missed that. Actually, I tested that hours ago, but couldn't get it to work either. But I probably had another bug as well then. :)

Comment: @AndersSjöqvist by the way, i prefer to initialize all structs with `&myStruct{...}` construct. Never let me down.

Answer (score 53):

In this part of the code, `ms` gets copied into an `interface{}` variable:

```
// Trying another method (UNSUCCESSFUL)
if ret, err := json.Marshal(ms); err != nil {
```

The problem is that this variable does not implement the `json.Marshaler` interface, since `MarshalJSON` is not in the [method set](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Method_sets) for `myStruct` (only for `*myStruct`).

The fix is to either (a) make your `MarshalJSON` method take a non-pointer receiver (which will mean it gets a copy of the struct: possibly costly if it is large), or (b) marshal a pointer to the struct (as Kavu mentioned in a comment).

The reason for this behaviour is that Go doesn't let you take a pointer to the value stored inside an interface variable, instead requiring you to make a copy of the value whenever you want to access it.  While the language has syntactic sugar to convert `ms.MarshalJSON()` into `(&ms).MarshalJSON()` as a way to access the method with a pointer receiver, this can not be done for a value stored in an interface variable.  For this reason, the method is not considered to be in its method set.

Comment: very instructive, `&myStruct{}` is a life-saving pattern